# Regular Expression For 3D Position

Tags: .net, regex

I am looking to validate a point in space as an input, in a .NET `DataGridView`. The input to the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` should be in this form:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

The `1.0` above represents the X,Y,Z axis (it could also be `0.1` or just `.1`). It must also contain the open and closing brackets.
As it is a position, it could be negative or positive and have n number of places after the decimal point.

Comment: I am not familair with .NET but is there no `is_number` or `is_float` function? You only want to check if it is a float, don't you?

Comment: in .Net there is a function which test if a string can be parsed to a number. float.TryParse in case of float, but integers, double and others base types have the same function. However, my guess is that he is looking to match the 3 coordinate at once while checking the format. The best way I know is using RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a RegEx, it should be something like that:

```
^ // The string should start with the left bracer
\[ // left bracer

([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+), // first float value followed by a virgule, this is matched
([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+), // second float value followed by a virgule, this is matched
([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+) // third float value, this is matched

\] // right bracer
$ // The string should end with the right bracer
```

Without comments this give you:

```
^\[([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+),([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+),([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\]$
```

If you want the regex to ignore any spaces you can add \s* between each element.

```
^\s*\[\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*,\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*,\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\]\s*$
```